# Importing csv/xls format files with smartGWT

Tags: smartgwt

I am using `smartgwt` free version (not EE). Is there a built in widget to handle importing `.csv` or `excel` format files? 
I can currently export records from a `listGrid` to `csv`. I want to be able to open up another browser, and import the `csv` file, and based on the configuration that I have exported onto the `csv` file, re-create the records that I have exported.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same thing, to achieve that I would suggest a custom datasource using gwt-rpc. You can get the code here.

https://code.google.com/p/smartgwt-extensions/

The thing is I've used gwtupload to send the excel file to the server. Once that is done call fetch to your custom datasource with the file path that was uploaded to the server. Using Apache POI on the server side to parse the data and return that as a result to your datasource fetch call. Within the execute fetch create Record objects and add them to your grid.

you can get the gwtupload from here,
https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted